# AWS IAM Group Policy to limit visibility & access to only one signle S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I created a bucket which host some web small web page and a few docs which should only be read accessible by users which have a certain login in IAM. These users should only have (read) access to this specific bucket and no other bucket. Ideally these users shouldn't even know that there are other buckets out there.

For this I create a "test" user in IAM, added the user to a group and assigned a group policy as below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListAndAlsoAllowGetBucketLocationRequiredForListBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3GetActionsInPrivateFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my.web.page/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

1. When I login with the test user and navigate to S3 I can see all my other buckets and when I click on another bucket I get a "Sorry, no permission" error. This kinda works but ideally the user shouldn't even be able to even list any other buckets.
2. When I go to https://s3.amazonaws.com/my.web.page/index.html I get a AccessDenied XML message. How can should I modify the policy to be able to open a html page in this bucket with a browser.
3. The user still has write access to the bucket. How can I only grant read access?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this policy it will work. Where it says example bucket put you bucket name

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGroupToSeeBucketListAndAlsoAllowGetBucketLocationRequiredForListBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3GetActionsInPrivateFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my.web.page/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```